# How to disable certain cells depending on custom uilabel values?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Currenly in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function i have subclassed two UILabels that holds the values inside the cells.

Lets say for example that the values presented in one cell is

**Value 1**                          **Value 2**

and if Value 2 is equals to `@"0,00"` That cell needs to be set disabled and have it's `cell.accessoryType` set to `None`

```
    -(UItableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {

            UITableViewCell *cell = [myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

            if (cell == nil)
            {
            cell = [self getCellContentView:CellIdentifier];
            }

            UILabel *lblValues = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];

            UILabel *lblsecValues = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];

            lblvalues.text = [values objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            lblsecValues.text = [secValues objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;


             /*
             if (  something..... ){

               //cell holding the `@"0,00"` 
               //cell.accessoryType = UITableViewAccessoryNone;

               //cell.setUserInteractionEnabled = NO;   


             }
             */
            return cell;            

        }
```

Any tips and/or suggestions how to find the proper condition will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [self getCellContentView:CellIdentifier];
    }

    UILabel *lblValues = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    UILabel *lblsecValues = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];

    lblvalues.text = [values objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    lblsecValues.text = [secValues objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if( [[secValues objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"0,00"] )
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewAccessoryNone;
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;   
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;   
    }

    return cell;            
}
```